# Number of nodes in Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

Im trying to setup a Hadoop Multi node cluster.

When I start my cluster here is my response in console..

```
hduser@hadoop-master:/usr/local/hadoop$ /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [hadoop-master]
hadoop-master: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-hadoop-master.out
hadoop-master: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-hadoop-master.out
hadoop-child: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-hadoop-child.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-hadoop-master.out
hduser@hadoop-master:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
21079 NameNode
21258 DataNode
21479 SecondaryNameNode
21600 Jps
hduser@hadoop-master:/usr/local/hadoop$ /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-hadoop-master.out
hadoop-child: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-hadoop-child.out
hadoop-master: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-hadoop-master.out
hduser@hadoop-master:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
21079 NameNode
21258 DataNode
22117 Jps
21815 NodeManager
21479 SecondaryNameNode
21658 ResourceManager
```

You can see a datanode being started in hadoop-child machine.

Now, when I try to get all the node information. I don't see all the nodes being displayed.

```
hduser@hadoop-master:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 21103243264 (19.65 GB)
Present Capacity: 17825124352 (16.60 GB)
DFS Remaining: 17821085696 (16.60 GB)
DFS Used: 4038656 (3.85 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.02%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 127.0.0.1:50010 (localhost)
Hostname: localhost
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 21103243264 (19.65 GB)
DFS Used: 4038656 (3.85 MB)
Non DFS Used: 3278118912 (3.05 GB)
DFS Remaining: 17821085696 (16.60 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.02%
DFS Remaining%: 84.45%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Sun Feb 26 17:13:04 UTC 2017
```

I need to view information of both master and child here. I have 1 master and 1 child node.

********************Fix*******

Based on Frank this is how it was fixed..

1. Edited the /etc/config file and gave both the master and child ipaddress.

changed the below 2 line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost hadoop-master
961.118.98.183 hadoop-child
```

to (in both nodes)

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
961.118.99.251 hadoop-master
961.118.98.183 hadoop-child
```

2.Restart the cluster in the following order..the datanode should be reformatted.

```
format will remove only the meta, the datanode's data directories will still be using the old namenode's identity which wil cause the datanode to fail(so delete the directories).

Can you please this order.. 
1) stop the cluster 
2) rm -rf /path/to/datanode/data/dir (in both nodes) 
3) hadoop namenode -format
4) START cluste
```

Comment: One of your datanodes is not running!

Comment: When I try the jps command in the child node..it shows its running.hduser@hadoop-child:/home/ubuntu$ jps
3286 NodeManager
3134 DataNode
3429 Jps

Comment: What is the value set in core-site.xml for property fs.defaultFS in both the nodes? Also the node reporting at the moment has the wrong hostname `localhost`.

Comment: I have not given any value for the fs.defaultFS..Im trying to follow http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up a multinode environment, the `namenode` and the `resourcemanager` addresses must be explicitly defined.

Add this property to `core-site.xml` in both the nodes,

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:8020</value>
</property>
```

Also this in `yarn-site.xml`,

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>hadoop-master</value>
</property>
```

Make sure in the `/etc/hosts` file of all the nodes, the IP address and hostname mapping is done.

**Note:** If the services are running, stop them and add these properties before starting them again.

Comment: Thanks..Still I get the same report when I run the dfsadmin report...Only one node is reported.Also,  Hostname as you mentioned earlier its still localhost

Comment: And the datanode reported has the name `localhost`?

Comment: Thats correct..Its exactly the same report that I have shown above.

Comment: And you restarted the entire cluster?

Comment: yes, thats correct.I ran the stop-dfs.sh and stop-yarn.sh command and restarted