# Hadoop add new datanode fail when build cluster

Tags: hadoop

I'm build a hadoop cluster, about two node, step by step with [official document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Monitoring_Health_of_NodeManagers).

But append datanode not join the cluster at Web UI: `http://{host address}:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-datanode`

with command:

```
[az-user@AZ-TEST1-SPARK-SLAVE ~]$ yarn node --list
17/11/27 09:16:04 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.0.4.12:8032
Total Nodes:2
         Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       Number-of-Running-Containers
AZ-TEST1-SPARK-MASTER:37164             RUNNING AZ-TEST1-SPARK-MASTER:8042                                 0
AZ-TEST1-SPARK-SLAVE:42608              RUNNING AZ-TEST1-SPARK-SLAVE:8042                                  0
```

It shows there are two node, but with another command just shows one livenode:

```
[az-user@AZ-TEST1-SPARK-SLAVE ~]$ hdfs dfsadmin -report 


Configured Capacity: 1081063493632 (1006.82 GB)
Present Capacity: 1026027008000 (955.56 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1026026967040 (955.56 GB)
DFS Used: 40960 (40 KB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
Pending deletion blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 10.0.4.12:50010 (10.0.4.12)
Hostname: AZ-TEST1-SPARK-MASTER
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1081063493632 (1006.82 GB)
DFS Used: 40960 (40 KB)
Non DFS Used: 97816576 (93.29 MB)
DFS Remaining: 1026026967040 (955.56 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 94.91%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Mon Nov 27 09:22:36 UTC 2017
```

command show the same result on Master node.

Thanks for any advice.

#### other messages

1. the problem similar as [number-of-nodes-in-hadoop-cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471625/number-of-nodes-in-hadoop-cluster) but not work on my stage.
2. I'm use bare ip not config host ip file as usual.

#### Fixed

Use host name in every node and their configuration file.
In cluster mode, it must use host name rather then bare ip.